# PayPal Orders v2: TRANSACTION_REFUSED and UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY

Tags: paypal

Good day, Paypal is not working on my website, which is a wordpress site.  I am getting this error.  Can anyone help?

Array
(
[code] => 40003
[userinfo] => Array
(
[error] => The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.
[data] => Array
(
[name] => UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY
[details] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[issue] => TRANSACTION_REFUSED
[description] => The request was refused
)

)

[message] => The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.
[debug_id] => d438b2beb9f7c
[links] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[href] => https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-TRANSACTION_REFUSED
[rel] => information_link
[method] => GET

Answer (score 0):

The important part of the error message is "TRANSACTION_REFUSED".  Because it was refused the request is unprocessable as a general matter, but other things can also lead to an unprocessable request.

Why was it refused? Usually an issue with the payer. However, if *all* payments to your account are being refused, then it is an issue with the receiving account. What is the country of the account? It may be missing some setup to be able to receive funds, such as a required withdrawal method for [certain countries](https://www.paypal.com/tt/webapps/mpp/ua/recpymt-full). Contact PayPal for details.